# how to group 59 elements into one element in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

so, i have a program that read value and its year from a textfile that starts from 1960 till 2018. each indicator code have different values but the year stays the same, 1960-2018. i have successfully read the textfile and store it in the arraylist.

however, values and its years from one indicator is not grouped in one element. but instead, it groups them one value(and its year), one element. AND let's say i have 2 indicator code, 59 values for each indicator code. they're all mixed up in 118 elements. i wanted them in 2 elements.

how to solve this problem so that each indicator code and its data(years and values) is in one element?

```
myLinkedList bigdata = new myLinkedList();
ArrayList <MyData> data = new ArrayList(); 
MyData d1;

File inFile2 = new File ("indicator2.txt");
FileReader fr2 = new FileReader (inFile2);
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);
String str2 = br2.readLine();

while(str2 != null ){
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str2,";");

        String cCode = st.nextToken();
        String iName = st.nextToken();
        String iCode = st.nextToken();

        for (int j = 0; j < 59; j++){ 
            String v = st.nextToken();
            int year = 1960 + j;

            d1 = new MyData (year,v);
            data.add(d1);
        }
            Indicator idct1 = new Indicator (cCode,iName,iCode,data);
            bigdata.insertAtBack(idct1);
            str2 = br2.readLine();
}
```

example of indicator2.txt:
MYS; Employment in industry (% of total employment) (modeled ILO estimate); SL.IND.EMPL.ZS; null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;31,72100067;31,62000084;32,01699829;32,22900009;32,34000015;32,23300171;33,6629982;31,76000023;31,70000076;32,18299866;33,11000061;31,97999954;32,02000046;30,12700081;29,72299957;30,26000023;28,45999908;28,68000031;27,01300049;27,73699951;29,08600044;28,56900024;28,36300087;28,02300072;27,51600075;27,48699951;27,39800072;27,30500031

(From left: cCode; iName; iCode; the values starting from 1960)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're writing the data into the same `ArrayList` over and over again for all indicator codes.  What if you moved the following statement:

```java
    ArrayList <MyData> data = new ArrayList();
```

Inside your `while loop`.  Then you would be creating a new `ArrayList` for each indicator code when your save it to an `Indicator` object.

Answer (score 0):

Generic types can be nested, so one solution would be to use an ArrayList of ArrayLists of MyData objects instead:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyData>>
```